# Vector calculations class oop php

Tags: php, oop, vector

I'm learning php oop and seems like i still do not understand of how some things work as my code, which, imo, looks properly doesn't work and returns few errors. This is the code:

```php
<?php

class Vector {

    private $x;
    private $y;

    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        if (is_nan($x) || is_nan($y)) {
            $this->x = 0 && $this->y = 0;
        } else {
            $this->set($x, $y);
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        var_dump($x, $y);
    }

    public function setx($x) {
        if (is_numeric($x)) {
            $this->x;
        }
    }

    public function sety($y) {
        if (is_numeric($y)) {
            $this->y;
        }
    }
    public function retLength() {
        return $x;
    }
    public function addVector() {
        $sum=$x+$y;
    }
    public function dotProduct() {
        $dot_product = array_sum(array_map(function($x,$y) { return $x*$y; }, $array1, $array2));
    }
}

$wekt= new Vector($x, $y);
echo $wekt->addVector(5,7);
```

Errors i get are: undefined variables "x" and "y" on line 42 (which is $wekt= new Vector($x, $y); ) and "Call to undefined method Vector::set()".

Specification for this class is:

- two private attributes $x and $y (seems to be ok)
- constructor receives $x and $y and on receive checks if these are numbers. Constructor is supposed to output message about just created vector.

I do not understand much all this constructor and probably this is one of reasons why this code doesn't work as it is intended to.

- destructor is supposed to output info about destroyed object.
- there should be available functions to change values of $x and $y
- there should be available function to return $x
- two more functions: one outputting sum of two vectors, second function supposed to output scalar product which takes as value a number.

Comment: `$x` and `$y` don't exist in the scope where you're doing the call to `new Vector()`

Comment: There is no `set()` method in your `Vector` class, only methods for `setx()` and `sety()`

Comment: http://php.net/variables.scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things in your code going wrong. See the following code:

```
class Vector {}

$wekt= new Vector($x, $y);
echo $wekt->addVector(5,7);
```

Where are `$x` and `$y` defined? This is the main reason you are getting the error. You class has a different scope then the global scope, meaning everything you define there is only accessible by `$wekt->` as `$wekt` is defined in the global scope.

Now the second thing is `addVector()`:

```
echo $wekt->addVector(5,7);
```

You ask to echo the return of this method, yet no return is defined in that function. Secondly where is the `$x` and `$y` defined within the scope of that function?

Change it to something like:

```
class Vector {
    private $list = [];
    public function addVector($x, $y) {
        $this->list[] = new Vector($x, $y);
        return $x + $y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I almost forgot i created this thread :-) So far i fixed this code and now it looks and works far better than this what i did here. Since answers to answers on stackoverflow have limit of signs i will not post the code in this post. Ultimately now i have a bit better understanding of constructors and i even can use them which is a good thing.

Comment: @spectatorx Than atleast mark it as it would have resolved your problem. Now I even forgot I made this answer, I'm just going back in history about all the unmarked / unvoted ones. ;)